# Can I assume there is homothety in this situation?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, homothety

I have found two similar triangles,the triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$. The lines connecting their respective vertices intersect at exactly one point, in other words concurrent. May I assume the intersection point is the center of homothety, which moves $ABC$ to $A_1B_1C_1$?

Answer (score 3):

No, e.g. start with an arbitrary 45-90-45 triangle $ABC$, pick any point $E$ on the circle (to ensure $\angle E = 90$) and then points $F$ and $G$ on $EC$ and $EB$ so that $\Delta ECB$ is also 45-90-45.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I see. What if the intersection point is not vertices of both triangles. In other words, what would happen if the intersection is different from $A, B, C, A_1, B_1, C_1$?

Comment: @Ualibek Nurgulan Just reflect $E$ against the $FG$ line.

Comment: Hmm. Then, I wonder if the situation will change when $\triangle ABC$ is not isosceless.

Comment: Oh yeah, plus the reflection of $E$ doesn't necessarily lie on$AE$.

Comment: @Ualibek Nurgulan Nothing will change - the triangle just gets reflected. The reflection of $E$ does lie on $AE$ because $EA$ is a bisector of $\angle CEB.$

Comment: I see but what about the case when it isn't isosceless?